# error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier

Tags: c++

i can't get rid of these errors... i have semicolons everywhere i checked...
the code is simple:
the error takes me to the definition "string name" in article.h...

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#include "article.h"

int main()
{
 string si;
 char article[128];
 vector<Article> articles;
 ifstream file;


 file.open("input.txt",ifstream::in);

 while(!file.eof())
 {
  file.getline(article,128);
  articles.push_back(Article(article));

 }

 file.close();

 while(1);
 return(1);
}
```

article.h:

```
#ifndef Article_H
#define Article_H

class Article
{
public:
 int year;
 string name;

 Article(char *i_name);
};

#endif
```

Comment: It compiles under OSX - so we need more information

Comment: Looks like it should work to me, and it works on GCC. `using namespace std;` before including a file is why wars happen, and you should be ashamed of yourself ;-) But aside from that, fine. Could it be that you're looking at the wrong source file, and there's some other source file which includes article.h without making `string` a valid type?

Comment: Compiles fine with VS2008 (once a ctor is added)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should add:

```
#include <string>
```

to your "article.h" header file and declare **name** like this:

```
std::string name;
```

Comment: It's true, you should, but I don't see why it would make any difference to whether the code compiles in this case.

Comment: the world's greatest (IMHO) language, has the most obscure errors. I miss java for it's beautiful errors, you could know EXACTLY what is wrong with your code, even as you're writing . Oh well...

Answer (score 3):

It seems the `string` type is not defined in the artivle.h file. Try to include `iostream` and add `using namespace std` (or write `std::string` instead of using namespace)

Comment: Don't include `iostream` in article.h: include `string`, which is all that header needs.

Comment: This is good practice as each header should be compilable if included on its own. However in his case it does not matter as string is defined before article.h is included

Answer (score 3):

You should use the std:: namespace prefix in the header, like

```
std::string name;
```

Comment: The putting `using namespace std` before the `#include` means this isn't needed and doesn't really explain the errors.  That said, relying on someone to put a `using namespace std` before including a header is pretty bad practice